# Format long numbers with a thousand separator?

Tags: formatting

In most language, long numbers are split into groups of three digits, to increase readability.

In Dutch (my native language), `1000000` is usually written as `1 000 000`. In English, this would be `1,000,000`.

Now, I would like to know how to use this kind of formatting in LaTeX. I searched google, but I only found some articles that explain how to split very long numbers over multiple lines, which is not what I need.

Is there a package that does this automatically? Or a certain tag I can use for this?

Comment: sorry I didn't realize it was latex, anyway searching "number formatting" will help you find something instead of split. for example this post: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=9548 hope it helps

Comment: [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) provides this functionality.

Comment: Or [`numprint`](http://ctan.org/pkg/numprint)

Comment: +1 for narrow space separation. I was taught in primary school in the Netherlands to use a dot, and that the Americans use a comma but that dot is european so we should use this. Later, I learned of other options like space and apostrophe which are unmistakable for a decimal separator and that just sounds like the obvious solution.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use `\,` for a thin space if you are entering by hand: `$1\,000\,000$`

You can also use a package such as [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), which inserts appropriate separators and spacing automatically: `\num{100000}`

Which one you should use depends on what you want to do (and where the numbers are generated); whether it's a few numbers in a hand-authored text or if you are typesetting thousands of numbers in table data where hand editing to add grouping separator is not really an option.

Comment: Is there any method to automatically apply siunitx to all the numbers of my document without needing to write \num in front of each one?
I would like to have all my numbers shown with groups of 3 digits and a small space in between.

Comment: @skan not really (but you could ask a new question see if anyone has any suggestions)

Comment: ... and _how_ do you do it with siunitx?

Comment: @Mayou36 I've edited the answer to answer your question: use `\num{1000000}`.

Comment: @FWDekker thanks

Answer (score 29):

There is a good package for all of these formatting issues with numbers, either in text or in tabular: `\usepackage{numprint}`. Please *study* the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/numprint), it provides a lot of detailed information. You get the manual usually with something like `texdoc numprint`on the command line.

A small MWE for numprint to answer your question:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{numprint}
\npthousandsep{\,}

\begin{document}

This would be a line with a price tag: \numprint{1000000} EUR.

And as a tabular: 
\begin{tabular}{N{7}{0}}
  1000000 {~EUR}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

We get this:

[image: numprint example]

As you can see, just tell numprint how the thousand separator should look like.
You can do much more, rounding numbers e.g.

Comment: Note that _numprint_ have an option to specify the unit this way `\numprint[EUR]{1000000}` or `\numprint[nm^2]{5}`

Comment: @Opsse I'm astonished, never noticed that option. Thank you!

Comment: Am I missing something here? You set `\npthousandsep{\,}`, but the rendered separator is a space.

Comment: @crockeea `\,` delivers a thin space.

Answer (score 4):

This is very interesting exercise for TeX macro programmers. My result looks like this:

```
\def\num #1{\numA#1\empty\empty\empty#1\end}
\def\numA #1#2#3{%
   \ifx #1\empty \afterelax{\numB}\fi
   \ifx #2\empty \afterelax{\numB{}}\fi
   \ifx #3\empty \afterelax{\ea\numB\ignoreit}\fi
   \ea \numA \ignoreit \relax
}
\def\numB #1#2#3#4{#1#2#3\ifx#4\end\else \numseparator \ea\numB\ea#4\fi}

\def\afterelax#1#2\relax{\fi#1}
\def\ignoreit#1{}
\let\ea=\expandafter

\def\numseparator{,}

Test: number \num{1234567}
```

The `\num` macro is expandable.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the package SIUNITX has solved this problem easily. Try`\usepackage[round-mode=places,round-precision=2,group-separator={,},output-decimal-marker={.}]{siunitx}` in your preamble, and use `\num{10000}`. For more usages see its CTAN manual.

Comment: Add `round-pad = false` to avoid zeros at the decimal place for integers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the package "Ziffer" which  helps if you want to write 100000 as "100.000,00" it will show "10 000,00" (no space after the comma and a space instead of the dot)

Comment: Please improve your answer with small. complete document, which will show syntax of using mentioned package.

Comment: Your comment would technically apply to the accepted answer as well.