# Typesetting numbers in binary format

Tags: typography, siunitx

I am writing a document that occasionally contains large numbers in binary format. I originally typeset them with spaces between groups of four digits, e.g. `1010 0110 0111 1100`. However, when copying these into math mode, the spaces disappear (from the output). To not end up with something as ineligible as `1010011001111100`, I would have to manually add spaces as in `1010 \, 0110 \, 0111 \, 1100`, which is a really annoying task.

At this point, I decided to turn to the `siunitx` package which offers a number of handy number typesetting options. By default, it splits numbers consisting of more than 4 digits into groups of 3. With binary, this would result in something like `1 010 011 001 111 100`, which is obviously undesirable. However, even after some searching in the documentation, I couldn't find an option to set number grouping to 4 digits per group. All I came up with was `\num[group-digits = false]{1111 1111 1111 1111}` which produces no spaces at all and would bring me back to square one.

So finally, my question is what is the best way to typeset binary numbers in `LaTeX`? A solution based on the `siunitx` package would be great.

Comment: For a siunitx solution you will probably have to make a feature request @JosephWright, for another solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230086/how-to-add-spaces-at-every-x-digit-in-a-binary-or-hexadecimal-number

Comment: `$\textrm{1111 1111 1111 1111}$`  ?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the link. Hadn't found that question yet. And egreg's solution works quite nicely. Still I'd prefer to use `siunitx` for this so I reached out to Joseph, as you suggested.