# format inline Sexpr number to include a comma

Tags: punctuation, knitr

I have the following inline code to call a value from R code.  The value called for example is 8000.  I would like to format the value so there is a comma for the 1,000 place - for example 8,000.

The inline code is:

```
$\text{\Sexpr{table1.1[4,3]}}$
```

I am using R Studio and pdfLaTex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either the `numprint` package or the `siunitx` package in combination with `\Sexpr`. Using `\text` is not necessary. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint}
\npthousandsep{,}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}, group-minimum-digits = 4}
\begin{document}
<<echo=FALSE>>=
a <- 8000
@
$a_1=\numprint{\Sexpr{a}}$    % using numprint

$a_2=\num{\Sexpr{a}}$         % using siunitx
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Of course when you use `numprint` you can delete the two lines about `siunitx` and vice versa. In general `numprint` is a bit easier to use but `siunitx` has (a lot) more features.

See also: [Format long numbers with a thousand separator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110281/format-long-numbers-with-a-thousand-separator), [Preserving thousands separator with siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133993/preserving-thousands-separator-with-siunitx).